# Flutter video player shows only the first frame of the video that I want to loop

Tags: flutter, dart, video, flutter-layout, flutter-video-player

I want to create a VideoPlayer class for my flutter application, where I can put a looping video. When I debug the app or I m running it in "release mode", the VideoPlayer shows only the first frame of the video.

This is the code from my videoplayer.dart file

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class clipVideo extends StatefulWidget {
  clipVideo() : super();
  final String title = "titlu video";

  @override
  _clipVideo createState() => _clipVideo();
}

class _clipVideo extends State<clipVideo> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/intro.mp4');
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
    _controller.setLooping(true);
    _controller.setVolume(1.0);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return Center(
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is my dependency from the public.yasml file

```dart
video_player: ^0.10.11
```

The flutter run has no errors whatsoever. Is it because the video has the size of 20MB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include in initState()

_controller.play();